# Pug displaying HTML code instead of rendering

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I started using Pug for my dynamic website. The thing is that instead of displaying a website, Express displays HTML code on my website. Whats surprising is the fact that sometimes the site generates. What can be the reason that it doesn't work? Here is the like of code responsible for rendering template:

`res.render('main', {name:result[0].name, surname:result[0].surname, age:result[0].age});`

Comment: Have you configured the express `view engine` correctly? See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html for more information.

Comment: I did everything from that website. As I said, it works from time to time.

Comment: Show your `index` or `server` code where `view engine` is configured.

Comment: Did all of that, still not working. It's actually reading the file, but instead of generating HTML, it's added to the body of the document

Comment: Alright, I switched to EJS and now everything is working fine. I think I'm gonna stick with it.